# Does openssl store the certificate of the server after verification is done?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, openssl

As per my understanding , openssl will verify the certificate of the server during ssl handshake , using the trusted CAs present in the CA certificate dir in the context. After the  server certificate is verified and handshake is done , does the openssl cache/store the verified server certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate is available as long the SSL connection is open by calling SSL_get_peer_certificate, see https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_get_peer_certificate.html. It is no longer available after SSL close.